# How can i use numpy allclose to compare arrays of variable length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My full code is:
https://pastebin.com/ChqTHRzY

Basically if the arrays i want to compare are exactly the same length, it works great. If they are shorter or longer it fail.
I want it to compare the values in moves_user against each group in arrayof_wins. The code does this but only when they are the same length, which isn´t going to be the case.
How can i get this to be compared despite having fewer or greater numbers of items in the "moves" arrays compared to the arrayof_wins?

I´ll paste the code here too in case you cant see the page above:

```
import numpy as np

arrayof_wins = [[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[11,21,31],[12,22,32],[13,23,33],[11,22,33],[13,22,31]]
moves_user = [22, 12, 32]
moves_computer = [21,22]

result = ""

moves_user.sort()
moves_computer.sort()

founduser = False
x = 0
while founduser == False and x <= 7:
    founduser = (np.allclose(moves_user, arrayof_wins[x]))
    x += 1


foundcomp = False
y = 0
while foundcomp == False and y <= 7:
    foundcomp = (np.allclose(moves_computer, arrayof_wins[y]))
    y += 1



if founduser == True:
    result = "You win!"
elif foundcomp == True:
    result = "Computer wins!"

print(result)
```

Comment: What should the result be of comparing two arrays of different lengths?

Comment: The result needs to be either true/false, or maybe an integer value of the number of matches per group. I want to compare each group of 3 integers against the variable length moves array. If the moves array contains the 3 numbers in any one of the groups then true, if it doesn't, then false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the elements are (arrays of) integers then you don't need `allclose`, which is meant for comparing floating point variables within a tolerance threshold. If I understand you correctly something like

```
founduser = False
for win in arrayof_wins:
    if set(win).issubset(set(moves_user)):
        founduser = True
        break
```

might work for you: the variable `founduser` will be `True` is any of the winning sequences is a subset of the `moves_user` array. This assumes that neither ordering nor repetitions matter. The final `break` statement is optional, but prevents unnecessary tests after the first match has been found. Of course it would be even better to do the conversion from lists to sets only once.

Comment: i have been trying this out, that is exactly what i needed, thank you so much!